# Ckeditor and Special Characters

Tags: ckeditor

Trying to add 1/8 to the special characters form on CKEditor.

I'm adding "frac18:'VULGAR FRACTION ONE EIGHTH'" to the en.js file but it doesn't show up in the form.

Is there something else I need to update?

Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You've got to add your character to [editor.config.specialChars](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-specialChars).